# JavaFX extract calendar-popup from DatePicker / only show popup

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker, calendar

I'm trying to build an CalendarView for an JavaFX application, to only display dates(no selecting required). Since the `DatePicker` class has a nice calendar popup I thought I might try to extract it so that I already have all the style-questions covered.

So is there an easy way to extract the DatePicker calendar popup and insert it into a new CalendarView?

I already looked at the `show()` method from the `ComboBoxBase` class to see what exactly happens when the popup is triggered but I have to admit I couldn't really get my head around it.

Alternatively I could think about simply edit the DatePicker in a way that only the popup shows all the time with the editor-TextField and button component always hiding, but again I couldn't quite figure out how to do that without hiding the popup as well. Also I would propably need to get the bounds of the popup to approptiately manage height and width in this alternativw, which again seems to be not that easy.

Comment: It would probably be much easier just to build it from scratch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the popup content of a DatePicker from a DatePickerSkin. See this demo for an implementation:

```
public class DatePickerPopupDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

            DatePickerSkin datePickerSkin = new DatePickerSkin(new DatePicker(LocalDate.now()));
            Node popupContent = datePickerSkin.getPopupContent();

            root.setCenter(popupContent);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image: popup content]

---

If the top bar is not needed, you can look it up and hide it.

```
DatePickerSkin datePickerSkin = new DatePickerSkin(new DatePicker(LocalDate.now()));
Node popupContent = datePickerSkin.getPopupContent();

// force a css layout pass to ensure that lookup calls work
popupContent.applyCss();
popupContent.lookup(".month-year-pane").setVisible(false);

root.setCenter(popupContent);
```

[image: popup content with hidden top bar]

**Update:**

As of JDK 9 `DatePickerSkin` is part of the Public API and using the closed `com.sun.[...]` implementation is no longer needed. (See [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/skin/DatePickerSkin.html))

Also, [as mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681975/javafx-extract-calendar-popup-from-datepicker-only-show-popup#comment74862801_34684268), to get the selected value you have to access the `DatePicker` from which you extracted the skin (by saving it as an variable for example).

```
DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(LocalDate.now());
DatePickerSkin datePickerSkin = new DatePickerSkin(datePicker);
Node popupContent = datePickerSkin.getPopupContent();
//[...]
LocalDate selectedDate = datePicker.getValue();
```

You can also listen to value-changes by adding a `ChangeListener` to the associated property:

```
datePicker.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<LocalDate>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends LocalDate> observable, LocalDate oldValue, LocalDate newValue) {
        System.out.println("New Value: " + newValue);
    }
});
//Or using neat lambda
datePicker.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println("New Value: " + newValue);
});
```

Comment: As of JavaFX 8, note that `DatePickerSkin` is not a public API class. (It will be a public API [class in JavaFX 9](http://download.java.net/jdk9/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/skin/DatePickerSkin.html), though the package name will change, and possibly the API.) It's [pretty straightforward](https://gist.github.com/james-d/ee8a5c216fb3c6e027ea) to implement this directly with whatever API you need (and omit that you don't need).

Comment: @Modus Tollens sorry for silly question but how to I add "eventlistener" to that calendar so that I can retrive the day that has been clicked...? (coming from android and new to javafx so a bit confused):S

Comment: @pb4now save the DatePicker in a variable, say "myDatePicker". Then you can read "myDatePicker.getValue()"

Answer (score 0):

To remove "month-year-pane" use:

```
DatePickerSkin datePickerSkin = new DatePickerSkin(date_picker);
Node popupContent = datePickerSkin.getPopupContent();
((DatePickerContent) popupContent).getChildren().remove(popupContent.lookup(".month-year-pane"));
```