# How to show only the JavaFX DatePicker calendar popup and no ComboBox in FXML?

Tags: javafx, datepicker, javafx-8, fxml

I want to remove the ComboBox of a DatePicker and only show the Calendar of the DatePicker instead.

Explained here:
[JavaFX extract calendar-popup from DatePicker / only show popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681975/javafx-extract-calendar-popup-from-datepicker-only-show-popup)

If I want to accomplish it in java I would do something like:

```
DatePickerSkin skin = new DatePickerSkin(new DatePicker());
Node calendarControl = skin.getPopupContent();
```

But how can I do this in FXML? (I use SceneBuilder)

```
<DatePicker id="datePicker" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="535.0" showWeekNumbers="true">
  <HBox.margin>
      <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
  </HBox.margin>
</DatePicker>
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can try it like this:</strike>

```
<DatePicker id="datePicker" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="535.0" showWeekNumbers="true" stylesheets="@yourCSS.css">
  <HBox.margin>
      <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
  </HBox.margin>
</DatePicker>
```

<strike>And `yourCSS.css` (in the same directory probably):</strike>

```
.date-picker-popup .month-year-pane {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

<strike>I tried to do it with inline css styles with the attribute style on the `DatePicker` element, but I didnt get it to work.</strike>

EDIT:

Got the question wrong. Im pretty sure you cant display the popup without the combobox of the `Datepicker` with FXML only.

Comment: I'm not sure if you got the question right. I only want to show the popup and not the ComboBox of the DatePicker. Wouldn't your solution not hide the popup? However I tried your solution but I see no difference in the behavior.

Comment: Okay. Got the question wrong. Need to try it out :)

Comment: @7twenty7 Im pretty sure you cant do it with FXML only. I tried some things out but it didnt work. But probably someone else comes up with another idea.