# How to keep the date picker calendar open in javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, calendar, scenebuilder

I am building an application in JavaFX and was wondering if there was any way to have a small sized calendar? Something like that of the date picker, but of course the date pickers calendar is only shown when the user clicks on the text field. I was wondering if there is any way to keep the calendar on the date picker to be constantly open?

Comment: Yeah, today's date should be shown, as well as other calendar functions like changing month, year etc.. All the features seen within the date picker

Comment: read that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681975/javafx-extract-calendar-popup-from-datepicker-only-show-popup